# what happens if you create a variable length array and compile using g++

Tags: c++, g++

Following code compiles fine since g++ allows it , but will it cause  undefined behavior ? Or my code will work fine ? what does it mean that c++ standard disallows variable length array if no error is generated on using it ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x;
   cin >> x;
   char abc[x];
   cout << sizeof(abc) << "\n";
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens should be documented in the g++ documentation. My _guess_ is that it'll follow the rules for VLA:s in C code pretty closely.

Comment: According to the C++ standard, the behavior for this code is undefined. However, C++ implementations such as GCC may provide non-standard extensions of C++, such as VLA support. Then, the behavior is undefined by the standard but may be defined by that particular implementation.

Comment: They do, but note that the C rules for VLAs are not the same as the C rules for regular, fixed size arrays. Initialization is very different and they, my opinion, make a mess of the `sizeof` operator. The C++ Standard is open to extensions, and GCC's VLA support is such an extension. The behaviour is well defined, though I'll admit to not being a fan of the behaviour and recommend not using VLA. They are an extremely easy way to insert bugs into a program, particularly when you allow a user to specify the size.

Comment: @user4581301 and at some point one will need to compile it using another compiler without VLA support.

Comment: I once found a better [documentation link than this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), but today it seems to be the best Google deems me worthy of seeing.

Comment: The big and nasty initialization difference: `int arr[x] = {0};` Initializes the first element to 0. If `x` is a compile-time constant, the rest of the array is also zeroed. If `x` is not a compile-time constant, the rest of the array is left containing whatever garbage happened to be where the array now lives in storage. This is a nasty surprise to many.

Comment: Some extra reading on the subject: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC documents its support of VLAs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (**emphasis mine**)

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and **as an
> extension GCC accepts them** in C90 mode ***and in C++***.

CLANG [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) too follows suit but mentions clearly that the standard doesn't accept (**emphasis mine**)

> GCC and C99 allow an array's size to be determined at run time. **This
> extension is not permitted in standard C++**. However, Clang supports
> such variable length arrays for compatibility with GNU C and C99
> programs.

If you would prefer not to use this extension, you can always disable it with
`-Werror=vla` to disallow compilation.

Comment: An extension to the above: `-pedantic` warns of use of ALL of GCC's non-Standard extensions.

Comment: ...and throw in `-pedantic-errors` for good measure. "_This is not equivalent to `-Werror=pedantic`, since there are errors enabled by this option and not enabled by the latter and vice versa._"